# How to remove icons from buttons

Tags: icons

I would like to ask you, how can I remove icons (see image) from buttons at "Zrusiť" and "Odstrániť"

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/5fe3284c421418ba8578fe4c98597cd7.png]

File manager: Nemo

Theme: Libra 2.2

OS: Ubuntu 14 LTS